# SELECT WHERE IN query using text string

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause, concatenation

I've had a bit of a look around, and tried a few things, but I can't seem to get this to work... Can anyone help?

```
$typeall = " ('House','Condo','Loft','Townhouse','Land')";

$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'houses' WHERE and category IN " .$typeall);
```

does not work

but if I type

```
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'houses' WHERE and category IN ('House','Condo','Loft','Townhouse','Land')");
```

it works perfect, why?

Thanks.

Comment: with numbers it works perfect for example with $typeall = " (1,2,3,4,5)";
no problem but with text strings it does not work.

Comment: How exactly your code "does not work"? Can you post error message (and maybe DB scheme also)?

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `and`:

```
WHERE and category IN ...
```

Into:

```
WHERE category IN ...
```

Comment: yes sorry the where and category was because it is a large query and I delete some code to make it easy and forgot thay AND.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$typeall = "'House','Condo','Loft','Townhouse','Land'";

$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'houses' WHERE and category IN (".$typeall.")");
```

may be variable $typeall is not working in brackets.

Comment: @Pablo why are you using and after where remove that. and then try.

Answer (score 0):

Don't quote table name, and drop extra `and`:

```
$typeall = " ('House','Condo','Loft','Townhouse','Land')";
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM houses WHERE category IN " .$typeall);
```